# How to create my own objects in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, object

I want to create my own class in an existing CodeIgniter project.

I will create an object (say Object1) from that class in a controller (based on the user ID). This object will retrieve data in DB to populate its variables.

I want to be able to use this object in any function of my controller, and if possible I want to transmit it to my views.

In a near future, I might add another object (say Object2) that would contain several Object1.

What's the proper way to do it ? I started to write it in a model but it seems unapropriate ..

Comment: Why does a model seem inappropriate?

Comment: `require_once(APPPATH.'library/yourLibraryName')` `$this->CI =  & get_instance();`

Comment: Well as far as I understand, a model is supposed to take care of data management (DB, webservices, files etc.). But my object will not only use DB stuff, it will also calculate things and do business logic. That's why I guess it's not apropriate to use a model here, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone's interested, I ended up using a normal php file that i store in /classes/.